# Homebrew warning: "No developer tools installed" even though Xcode is installed

Tags: terminal, xcode, homebrew, git

After installing Homebrew the "brew doctor" command returns:

```
Warning: No developer tools installed.
You should install the Command Line Tools.
Run `xcode-select --install` to install them.
```

…and I do have Xcode installed.

Anyway, after running `xcode-select --install` the Xcode installer appears, then I click "install" and the installer closes.

Is this normal? …and do I have to install Git from Homebrew, or can I use the one that comes with Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode itself isn't what i needed to install, it was Specifically the "Xcode Command Line Tools", apparently thats a different thing...

Comment: IIRC, Xcode Command Line Tools is a subset of Xcode. Xcode itself is quite big, comes with all the command line tools AND other stuff like IDE, SDKs, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is perfectly normal for homebrew to prompt you to install Xcode. That happened to me right after I installed Mavericks.

As for your question about git, it depends a lot on your usage. Default git (and almost every other tools) are not of the latest version. If you're OK with that, then of course you can just use the default one.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Xcode installed this warning also appear even if make and gc is succesfully provided by Xcode itself. In this case you can just ignore this warning.